# Customizing Info Window in FusionTableMapLayer

Tags: google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I am calling a FusionTableMapLayer via the Fusion Table API.  I have developed a customized info window for the layer in the actual Google Fusion Table program but when I call the layer in my application, the Info Window reverts to the default Info Window.  How do I either a) call the customized Info Window that is saved in the Google Fusion Table or b) customize the Info Window as part of my API call?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code exported from the wizard (or at least the styleId and templateId from it)

```
new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: "geometry",
    from: "1EPhndJHBm0ghi06Xq9d8P62hUwCisAcQxYxgH5ax",
  },
  map: map,
  options: {
    styleId: 2,    // get these values from the proper tab on the FusionTables UI
    templateId: 2  // get these values from the proper tab on the FusionTables UI
  }
});
```